# Translation error while using python package "googletrans"

Tags: python, excel

1. I want to fix the below code, it should translate the words located in column A in the excel called "translation.xlsx", but it gives me an error
2. Also it should give me the output/result(translated words) in the same excel(translation.xlsx") in column B.

code is here

```
import openpyxl
from googletrans import Translator

loc = r"C:\Users\userid\Desktop\translation.xlsx"

gs = Translator.translate()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.active

for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    original = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    translated = gs.translate(original, 'de')
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = translated

wb.save(loc)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\userid\translation.py", line 8, in <module>
    gs = Translator.translate()
TypeError: translate() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'text'
```

Comment: It's a `TypeError`, not translation error. You want `gs` to be instance of `Translator` class, so it has to be `gs = Translator()`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the function `translate()` with the `Translator` class itself, not an instance of it.

Try:

```py
gs = Translator()
```